# Spring for Apache Kafka: Unrecognized producer configuration - 'delivery.timeout.ms'

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a spring boot application with Spring for Apache Kafka being used to send messages to topics on a kafka cluster.  I've autowired a property for **[delivery.timeout.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs)** and after the application starts and the producer is configured, the application logs show the property's value was not set and it gives the warning: `"WARN  [task-scheduler-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig [] --- The configuration 'delivery.timeout.ms' was supplied but isn't a known config"`

I've checked my POM and confirmed that I'm using the following two dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I've also confirmed that the property existed in version 2.1.0:  https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.html

I see posts with a similiar warning for other properties mentioning that it can be ignored; however, my application is experiencing undesirable behavior which could be corrected by setting this property based on its description.

Comment: Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55456262/4405757)?

Comment: @user7 yes, I believe so.  As I mentioned other posts mention it can be ignored.  However, in my case it appears to not be getting set at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your kafka-clients version override is not working. I just tested it and it worked fine (with spring-kafka 2.2.9 and the 2.1.1 clients):

```
ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 123456
    enable.idempotence = false
    ...
```

Try following the [instructions in the Spring for Apache Kafka reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#deps-for-21x) for overriding all the kafka client libraries.

Comment: You are correct.  Viewing the maven dependency tree is showing that a much older version of the library is being pulled in from somewhere and the one Ive specified is being excluded.